# scrollbar in firefox and opera

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have a little issue related to scrollbars. The question is that I have a set of boxes within a container. All the content is fixed the max width of the container and once the number of elements within the container grow, the overflow-y property start working.

In Firefox and opera, (i do not know in IE) the width of the scrollbar come up and destroy my layout passing from three columns to two.

Here i have the code: http://jsfiddle.net/domoindal/ChkRg/

If you run it in Chrome and Safari, it works fine due to the scroll bar appear over the content but in Firefox and Opera don't.

Is there any way i could avoid this effect in the quoted browsers?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain better what is the issue with Firefox and Opera? I can't see any difference between my firefox (13) and my chrome in your example. I have a scrollbar in firefox and in chrome.

Comment: I have a three columns layout with boxes and in Firefox, when the content overflow in 'y' and the scrollbar appear, the layout pas to two columns.

Comment: When I open your fiddle example, I only have 2 columns. Are you sure you have not zoomed in your browser with `Ctrl + plusKey` or `Ctrl + Scroll`? Check firefox and Chrome please. Try `Ctrl + 0` or `Ctrl + Alt + 0` to reset the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand you issue, though I'm surprised it works in Chrome since it doesn't work for me. (using Chrome too)
My first thought to increase the width, so the scrollbar'll have enough space.
You can detect with javascript if the content grew too high, then resize.